# Resize outer-div (relative pos) min-height to height of inner-div (absolute pos)

Tags: html, css, alignment

I'd like to have a couple of divs that are at least the height of the viewport.

```
.fullheight {
   position: relative;
   min-height: 100vh;
}
```

Each of those contains other divs and in case the content is taller than the viewport-height, the `fullheight` div should grow. 
**While that works well if the content divs are also "position: relative", it doesn't if I use absolute positions for the inner divs.** (Which I use center vertically.)

I put together a jsfiddle to illustrate my problem (the overflow on div2): [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y0qb7w2e/3/)

```css
body {
  font-size: 5rem;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.fullheight {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}

.color1 {
  background-color: #3ff;
}

.color2 {
  background-color: #f3f;
}

.color3 {
  background-color: #ff3;
}

.content {
  position: absolute;
  width: auto;
  top: 50%;
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="fullheight color1">
<div class="content">
1
</div>
</div>
<div class="fullheight color2">
<div class="content">
2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 
</div>
</div>
<div class="fullheight color3">
<div class="content">
3
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a *flexbox* for the *vertical centering* (don't use *absolute positioning* here as `position: absolute` takes your element out of the flow which is why you have issue with your height).

Add `display: flex` and `align-items: center` on the `fullheight` - see demo below and [**`updated fiddle`**](https://jsfiddle.net/20nvprjg/):

```css
body {
  font-size: 5rem;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.fullheight {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex; /* added */
  align-items: center; /* added */
}

.color1 {
  background-color: #3ff;
}

.color2 {
  background-color: #f3f;
}

.color3 {
  background-color: #ff3;
}

.content {
  /*position: absolute;*/
  width: auto;
  /*top: 50%;
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%); // */
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="fullheight color1">
<div class="content">
1
</div>
</div>
<div class="fullheight color2">
<div class="content">
2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 
</div>
</div>
<div class="fullheight color3">
<div class="content">
3
</div>
</div>
```